# Could someone point out the error in my logic. (Coding Exercise)

Tags: python, logic

So this is a question form the website HackerRank. I've given it my best shot and I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. The question goes as follows:

"It is New Year's Day and people are in line for the Wonderland rollercoaster ride. Each person wears a sticker indicating their initial position in the queue from `1` to `n`. Any person can bribe the person directly in front of them to swap positions, but they still wear their original sticker. One person can bribe at most two others.

Determine the minimum number of bribes that took place to get to a given queue order. Print the number of bribes, or, if anyone has bribed more than two people, print `Too chaotic`."

This is my attempt:

```
def minimumBribes(q):
    bribes = 0
    sorted_q  = sorted(q)
    total_moves = 0
    for i in range(len(q)):
        origin = sorted_q[i]
        current = q[i]
        moved = current - origin
        if moved > 0:
            if moved > 2:
                print("Too chaotic")
                return
            else:
                total_moves += moved
    print(total_moves)
```

I realize it's a bit wordy but I wanted to make my logic as clear as possible.

If I input `q = [1,2,5,3,7,8,6,4]` the expected output is `7` but I get `6`

WHY!

Comment: I just saw that someone already posted a solution to this question in [hackerrank new year chaos code optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797194/hackerrank-new-year-chaos-code-optimization?rq=1) but I'm more interested in finding out why my solution isn't working.

Comment: If you write this out by hand, you'll see that 6 had to bribe 4 as well.  They're not just out of place, they're out of order (6>4).

Comment: So what you're saying is by simply taking the difference between the current position and the original position, I'm missing a bribe?

Comment: Right.  The fact that 6 and 4 are not in order means there must have been a bribe, but I haven't come up with a quantitative way to determine that.

Comment: Ah, I see it now.  There are 2 smaller numbers to the right of 5, there are 2 smaller numbers to the right of 7, there are 2 smaller numbers to the right of 8, and there's one smaller number to the right of 6.  That makes 7.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I think I get how to do the question now. I just hope this next solution doesn't take too long on longer lists, as it involves allot of scanning. It's fine for a small list like this but could potentially time out, given that they could pass me 10 lists of size 10^5. Questions like this always make me question my decision to become a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

q=[1,2,5,3,7,8,6,4]

as you look in the question there is no order of bribe is mention one could bribe 2
people at a time or 1 people at a time

there is no restriction that you cannot bribe if you get bribed by someone

let us reverse the hole process and create this situation back like that in "q"

'''

```
   sorted_q=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
   5 bribed 3 and 4 
   total_moved = 2
   
   sorted_q=[1,2,5,3,4,6,7,8]
   7 bribed 4 and 6 
   total_moved = 4
    
   sorted_q=[1,2,5,3,7,4,6,8]
   8 bribed 4 and 6
   total_moved = 6

   sorted_q=[1,2,5,3,7,8,4,6]
   here at this bribe by 6 to 4 just make your logic fail
   total_moved = 7
   

   sorted_q=[1,2,5,3,7,8,6,4]
```

'''

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, how to figure this out given the ending position?  You really haven't answered the question.

Comment: yeah i give the points were he was wrong and i thought he will observe it and get to the new solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797194/hackerrank-new-year-chaos-code-optimization?noredirect=1&lq=1 t

Comment: as solution was available so i only told about the part he was going wrong on

Answer (score 0):

I'm also answering this question

```
def minimumBribes(q):
# Write your code here
result = 0
for l in range(len(q)-1,0,-1):
    if q[l]!=l+1:
      if q[l-1]==l+1:
          result+=1
          q[l-1],q[l]=q[l], q[l-1]
          
      elif q[l-2]==l+1:
          result+=2
          q[l-2],q[l-1],q[l]=q[l-1],q[l],q[l-2]
      else:
          print("Too chaotic")
          return(0)
print(result)
```

this is my answer use languange python 3. But actually I can't promise if that's true for your case too. My advice is you should try it and be more careful. Thank you :). And if you have a feedback to me please share in comment